# How to update a column in same table using calculated value in oracle trigger

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers, mutating-table

I am creating a trigger in oracle where I need to update a column "subtotal" whenever there is an update in column "quantity" of the same table. so my update command which should fire this trigger is :

Update TABLENAME set QUANTITY = 6 where Order_ID = 601 AND ITEM_SEQ = 4 ;

This should fire the following trigger i have :

```
AFTER UPDATE ON TABLENAME 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   IF UPDATING THEN UPDATE TABLENAME
          SET SUBTOTAL =  :NEW.QUANTITY * ACTUAL_PRICE
          WHERE  order_id = :NEW.order_id;
   END IF;
END;
```

However i am getting a mutating error issue ORA-04091. I searched and found that this is generally when the table is updating and we try to insert values to it , however i used "AFTER" command and so the table should have been updated by then.
Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption is that you are merely trying to update the particular row that caused the trigger to fire.  And that `actual_price` is also coming from the row being modified.  If so, you'd do that simply by assigning a value to the `:new.subtotal`.  But you'd have to do it in a before update trigger not an after update trigger.

```
create or replace trigger your_trigger_name
  before update on your_table_name
  for each row
begin
  :new.subtotal := :new.quantity * :new.actual_price;
end;
```

If this is not a homework assignment, it would be more efficient and less error-prone to define `subtotal` as a computed column in the table rather than trying to maintain the data in a trigger.

Comment: This worked !! Thanks a ton Justin ! 
What i thought as a logic was that AFTER i run update command, the fields QUANTITY and ACTUAL_PRICE are updated and so i can use the values to compute the subtotal amount. Can you help me understand why we have used :new while the field ACTUAL_PRICE had no new value. Only value that we updated via command was QUANTITY.

Comment: @pun_intended - `actual_price` did have a new value.  It happened to be the same as the old value if you didn't change it.  The `:new` pseudo-record has the new value for every column in the current row, the `:old` pseuco-record has the prior value for every column in the current row.  You could compare the `:new` and `:old` values if you wanted (making sure to keep `null` comparison semantics in mind) to determine if the `update` statement actually changed the value in a particular column.

Comment: Another option would be to create your column as a generated virtual column.  create table ... as (... subtotal number(10,4) generated always as (round(actual_price * quantity, 4)) virtual ...); This eliminates the trigger(s) altogether and prevents an inadvertent "set subtotal ..."  Note (10,4) just used to example.